# page is not redirecting after using mysqli prepare statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = ? AND password = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($member = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['email'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location:home.php");
    }
} else {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Wrong Username or Password';
    $errflag = true;
    if ($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index.php");
    }
}
```

html form :

```
<form role="form" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Log In" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This code is no redirecting to home.php .. It's showing Wrong Username or Password .. New to mysqli prepare statement.So any help here

Comment: I guess it's a typo, but you shoudn't store passwords in a session ;)

Comment: You only expect one result, right? Then you don't need the `while` loop. And as @Roboroads said, storing passwords in sessions isn't a good idea.. ;-)

Comment: Is `$_POST['username']` the users email address? Your code seems to be very inconsistent when it comes to have variable names carrying the load.

Comment: i unset the session on the index page only.. and removed the while loop .. and its still not going to home page

Comment: @StillLearning Can you post us the HTML of your login form too?

Comment: it's just a demo version .. edited some parts only to do it in mysqli .. so dint bother to change the variable names ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Seems like this is the correct way to get at it:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = ? AND password = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Also, [This page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) sais:

> Execute: Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Execute does not return your result, but a boolean.